# Crypto Currency ICO process

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ether

I just want to know the process once we create the our own coin for ico do we need to create our own wallets and exchange as well, what is the process to transfer your own coin based on ether to your investors during ico.

what i have understood:

1. Go to Etherium.
2. Create 100M Coins
3. Call them "Sam Coin"
4. You than make a "Pre ICO"
5. You than market your idea.
6. You than issue your coin to those who send you money because they are investing in your idea...

Now for #6, I have read that you can issue them manually / direct, you can also automate this process but most icos that start off with an "idea" will do it manually so they can spend most of their time on marketing and less on the actual code.

is this right or i need a blockchian developer who is going to create my own wallets for this purpose.

If i have created my own coin on ether and i have default wallet on ether, how can i transfer token or my own coin to my investor's, manually, do i need a developer for this process for creation of wallets?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating and issuing your own coins on Ethereum, then they are done through a `Smart Contract` and not issued manually. Here is an example of a smart contract for creating a new token: https://www.ethereum.org/token

Generally the process (just for the contracts alone) is as follows:

1. You write the smart contract and deploy it
2. Your investors send Ether to the smart contract during the ICO period
3. The smart contract releases the tokens to them automatically through the code you have written

Whether you want to create a new wallet for the ICO or use your existing one is up to you and you will most definitely require a developer as you will need to write the code for the smart contracts.